# My Spring-Boot Autowired dependency isn't being fulfilled

Tags: spring-boot

My pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.kable.batch</groupId>
<artifactId>release-processing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Release Processing</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <hibernate.validator.version>6.0.13.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <log4j.version>2.19.0</log4j.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.7.4</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>com.kable.batch.release_processing.ReleaseProcessing</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My main class

```
package com.kable.batch.release_processing;

import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.kable.batch.release_processing.dao.ReleaseDao;
import com.kable.batch.release_processing.entity.koms.ReleaseSchedule;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ReleaseProcessing {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
ReleaseDao releaseDao = null;

public ReleaseProcessing() {
    try {
        logger.info("Hello World!");
        List<ReleaseSchedule> schedules = releaseDao.listScheduleForCompany(371l);
        logger.info("Number of schedules {}", schedules.size());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in Main");
        logger.error("Error", ex);
    }
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReleaseProcessing.class, args);
}
}
```

My folder layout

[image: My folder Layout]

My ReleaseDaoImpl in the com.kable.batch.release_processing.dao.impl package

```
@Repository("releaseDao")
@Transactional("transactionManagerKOMS")
public class ReleaseDaoImpl implements ReleaseDao {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactoryKOMS;

@Override
public List<ReleaseSchedule> listScheduleForCompany(Long companyId) {
    logger.error("Test Error");
    System.out.println("in DaoImpl");
    Session session = sessionFactoryKOMS.getCurrentSession();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ReleaseSchedule> query = builder.createQuery(ReleaseSchedule.class);
    Root<ReleaseSchedule> releaseSchedule = query.from(ReleaseSchedule.class);

    query.where(builder.equal(releaseSchedule.get("companyId"), companyId)).orderBy(builder.asc(releaseSchedule.get("startTime")));
    
    return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
}
```

My Hibernate Configuration in the com.kable.batch.release_processing.hibernate package

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfigurationKOMS {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConfigurationKOMS.class);

@Value("${db.sqlServer.userName}")
private String userName = null;

@Value("${db.sqlServer.password}")
private String password = null;

@Value("${db.sqlServer.serverName}")
private String serverName = null;

@Value("${db.sqlServer.portNumber}")
private Integer portNumber = null;

@Value("${db.sqlServer.databaseName}")
private String databaseName = null;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSourceKOMS() {
    SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setServerName(serverName);
    dataSource.setPortNumber(portNumber);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactoryKOMS() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryKOMS = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryKOMS.setDataSource(dataSourceKOMS());
    sessionFactoryKOMS.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.kable.batch.release_processing.entity.koms" });
    sessionFactoryKOMS.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    try {
        sessionFactoryKOMS.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }

    return sessionFactoryKOMS.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerKOMS() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactoryKOMS());
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");

    return properties;
}
}
```

As you can see, the DaoImpl is annotated as well as the hibernate beans as well as the @SpringBootApplication on my main class. It appears as if Spring isn't filling in the @Autowired dependency for the dao, because I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.kable.batch.release_processing.dao.ReleaseDao.listScheduleForCompany(java.lang.Long)" because "this.releaseDao" is null
at com.kable.batch.release_processing.ReleaseProcessing.<init>(ReleaseProcessing.java:25) ~[classes/:?]
at com.kable.batch.release_processing.ReleaseProcessing$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a5da2d30.<init>(<generated>) ~[classes/:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found another article that talks about this topic [here](https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/#constructor). The last item on the list talks about using autowired fields in the constructor. Which makes sense since the class isn't instantiated yet, so the fields can't be filled. So I made my main class `extend CommandLineRunner`, moved the code in the constructor method to the `public void run(String... args)` method and now everything works.